# What wrong with deallocating func?

Tags: c, list, dealloc

I am currently learning lists, and I am trying to write a function that deallocates the memory. I tried, but even though it compiles, it returns a non-zero value. I don't understand why my program doesn't return 0 when I use the deallocating function in the main function. However,the program is executed successfully when I don't use the deallocating function. To me the function seems fine. I can't spot the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct person {
    int age;
    struct person *next;
} person;

void insert_start(person **head, int x);
void insert_end(person **head, int x);
void insert_position(person **head, int x, int position);
void deallocating(person **head);

int main() {
    person *head = NULL;
    person p1 = { 2, NULL };
    person p2 = { 3, NULL };
    head = &p1;
    p1.next = &p2;
    insert_end(&head, 4);
    insert_start(&head, 12);
    insert_position(&head, 100, 3);

    for (person *curr = head; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
        printf("%d\n", curr->age);
    }

    deallocate(&head);

    return 0;
}

void insert_start(person **head, int x) {
    person *nextnode = malloc(sizeof(person));
    nextnode->age = x;
    nextnode->next = *head;
    *head = nextnode;
}

void insert_end(person **head, int x) {
    person *nextnode = malloc(sizeof(person));
    nextnode->age = x;
    nextnode->next = NULL;

    person *find = *head;
    while (find->next != NULL) {
        find = find->next;
    }
    find->next = nextnode;
}

void insert_position(person **head, int x, int position) {
    person *nextnode = malloc(sizeof(person));
    nextnode->age = x;
    nextnode->next = NULL;

    person *find = *head;
    int curr = 1;
    while (curr != position) {
        find = find->next;
        curr++;
    }
    nextnode->next = find->next;
    find->next = nextnode;
}

void deallocate(person **head) {
    person *curr = *head;

    while (curr != NULL) {
        person *del = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        free(del);
    }
    *head = NULL;
}
```

Comment: You can only `free` what has been allocated by `malloc`. `p1` and `p2` in the `main` function have not been allocated by `malloc`, yet you try to `free` them.

Comment: @JOHN BOURAS Also functions  insert_end and insert_position can invoke undefined behavior. And within  all functions you should check whether a new node was allocated successfully.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems:

These lines in `main` are pointless:

```
    person p1 = { 2, NULL };
    person p2 = { 3, NULL };
    head = &p1;
    p1.next = &p2;
```

It creates a mix of statically and dynamically allocated nodes which cannot be handled with without major hassle, because sooner or later you will end up freeing a statically allocated node which cannot work. Just don't do it

Then the prototype `void deallocating(person **head);` is wrong, the name of your function is `deallocate`. Your compiler should have warned you at least.

And last but not least, your insert functions are wrong. The case of the `head` being NULL needs special handling, as shown in the code below.

I leave it as an exercice to you to correct the other insert functions.

The `deallocate` functions looks OK to me.

Another thing is that `malloc` may return NULL (although this is unlikely with simple exercises like this one on a desktop computer) and you should check this. You can handle this at a later stage.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct person {
  int age;
  struct person* next;
} person;

void insert_end(person** head, int x);

int main() {
  person* head = NULL;
  
  insert_end(&head, 4);
  insert_end(&head, 5);

  for (person* curr = head; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
    printf("%d\n", curr->age);
  }

  return 0;
}

void insert_end(person** head, int x) {
  person* nextnode = malloc(sizeof(person));
  nextnode->age = x;
  nextnode->next = NULL;

  if (*head == NULL)  // if head is null the person just created
  {                   // becomes the head
    *head = nextnode;
    return;
  }

  person* find = *head;
  while (find->next != NULL) {
    find = find->next;
  }
  find->next = nextnode;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that in your deallocate function:

The first time del takes the value of curr, then you deallocate del, but del and curr are now the same. Then you use curr->next, but curr is no longer valid.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer addresses the wrong part. The `deallocate` function is correct, the problems are elsewhere.